# Edit command from Gridview to Formview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, formview

I've got a Gridview that lists some SQL data.
And i've got a Formview setup with edit template.
I then want a LinkButton in Gridview, to open edit in formview, with the selected entry in gridview.

I've got this to capture my edit command from Gridview, but how i then trigger my Formview i dont know?

```
public void newsEdit_Command(Object sender, CommandEventArgs e) {
    //Trigger formview edit from here...
    //e.CommandArgument contains my ID of the selected row in gridview.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the way you want, i think it is not possible.

You can do it in a simple way as:

1) Show Data in a grid view, When a user selects a row in the grid view, show that row data in the form view ( or you can use a details view  )

2) After displaying data in form view, Now edit it's row.

Comment: How would you do that then? you would pretty much have to do the same thing?
Sending a view command from gridview to formview?

Comment: yes you have to show the data in the formview. In your case the problem is that you can't trigger formview from inside of gridview.